# generic object creation with type as function parameter in c#

Tags: c#, json, generics, xamarin, default

I'm trying to create a generic function to parse my json result with Newtonsoft:

```
private T ParseResult<T>(string queryResult)
{
    Result res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(queryResult);

    if (res.Success == 1)
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res.data));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

If there is a problem with Success or the parsing I want to return an empty object of whatever T is (currently lists or just custom objects).

My problem is that the current solution is returning null instead of an empty object. How can I achieve that the return value will never be null.

Comment: Maybe you should embrace the `null` in this case. That is the only way to distinguish an empty data object from a non-existant data object, right?

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res.data))` looks hacky. Maybe you can make `Result` generic (like `Result<T>`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Irregardless of whether this is the right or wrong approach. The problem is `default(T)` will return the *default* for the *type*, for *Reference Types* that is `null`. If you want an *"empty object"* (new object) then you will have to use the [new constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) and `new` it up (instantiate it)

**Example**

```
private T ParseResult<T>(string queryResult) where T : new()
{

    ...

    return new T();

}
```

***Note*** : There are caveats though

[new constraint (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint)

> The new constraint specifies that any type argument in a generic class
>   declaration **must have a public parameterless constructor**. To use the
>   new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

---

**Additional Resources**

[default value expressions (C# programming guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions)

> A default value expression `default(T)` produces the *default* value of a
>   type `T`. The following table shows which values are produced for
>   various types:
>
> - Any reference type : `null`
> - Numeric value type : `0`
> - `bool` : `false`
> - `char` : `\0`
> - `enum` : The value produced by the *expression* `(E)0`, where `E` is the `enum` identifier.
> - `struct` : The value produced by setting all value type fields to their *default* value and all *reference type* fields to `null`.
> - Nullable type : An instance for which the `HasValue` property is `false` and the Value property is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`T` could be a class that does not have a default constructor: in this case new `T()` would be an invalid statement.

If you want to return with the default object you can use `Activator.CreateInstance` instead of returning `default(T)` as below:

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
```

if you want to pass parameters in it, then use as below:

```
return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), args);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I ended up creating this function which seems to work and I think is a better approach:

```
    private static T ParseResult<T>(string queryResult) where T : new()
    {
        try
        {
            Result<T> res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result<T>>(queryResult);

            if (res.Success == 1)
            {
                return res.Data;
            }
            return new T();
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            return new T();
        }
    }
```

and

```
internal class Result<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public int Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```